# Why is this table locked while procedure is running?

Tags: sql-server, locking

I have a MS SQL Server procedure that's basically a wrapper for a couple other procedures, and that logs it's process to a logging table as it runs.

Basically this:

```
insert into myLogTable(message, session_id)
    select 'Starting First Proc', @session_id

exec longRunningProc

insert into myLogTable(message, session_id)
    select 'Starting Next Proc', @session_id

exec nextLongRunningProc

insert into myLogTable(message, session_id)
    select 'Done', @session_id
```

While it's running, it keeps a lock on the myLogTable the whole time. If I use a nolock hint, I can query myLogTable, but what surprised me was that while nextLongRunningProc is running, the row written before it (where message = 'Starting Next Proc') is locked - I don't get that row returned until nextLongRunningProc is finished.

I'm curious why that row would be locked and if there's anything I can do in the main procedure to make sure it's unlocked after writing that row.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses an implicit [`TRANSACTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  Use explicit transactions to customise your transactions in order to limit the duration of the locks.  For example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION first_name;
insert into myLogTable(message, session_id)
COMMIT;

BEGIN TRANSACTION second_name;
select 'Starting First Proc', @session_id
exec longRunningProc
insert into myLogTable(message, session_id)
COMMIT;

BEGIN TRANSACTION third_name;
select 'Starting Next Proc', @session_id
exec nextLongRunningProc
insert into myLogTable(message, session_id)
select 'Done', @session_id
COMMIT;
```